# SQLite data in a ListView inside a Fragment

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-fragments, android-sqlite

I have created half of my app and I am stuck where I need to retrieve the data from the SQLite database and show them in a ListView inside a Tab Fragment.
I have two tabs and one of them will show the list of data from SQLite database.

Some people on stackoverflow suggested to use a RecyclerView instead of a ListView but it is difficult for me to use a ListView and I know nothing about the RecyclerView.
I am new to Android and I feel that these problems aren't that difficult for professional developers, but for me it is quite challenging.

I am able to show the data from the database in a Fragment, but I am able to show only one row which is the latest entry.
I want to display the whole list in the Fragment from latest to old , top to bottom.

The other part of the problem is that the list doesn't update automatically.
I need to close the app and reopen it to see the latest entry in the Fragment.

Here is my code -

**PeopleFragemnt.class** **Before**

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.kevin.sugar.DataBase.DateBaseHelper;
import com.example.kevin.sugar.DataBase.Information;
import com.example.kevin.sugar.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class PeopleFragment extends Fragment {

    DateBaseHelper dateBaseHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    Cursor cursor;

    TextView name,weight,height;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.person_row, container, false);

        name = (TextView)mview.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
        weight = (TextView)mview.findViewById(R.id.heatbeat);
        height = (TextView)mview.findViewById(R.id.bpm_upper_lower);

        dateBaseHelper = new DateBaseHelper(getContext());
        sqLiteDatabase = dateBaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = dateBaseHelper.getUserInformation();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                String user_name,user_weight,user_height;
                user_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Information.NAME));
                user_weight = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Information.WEIGHT));
                user_height = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Information.HEIGHT));

                Log.e("App",user_name+ "" + user_height + " " +user_weight);
                name.setText(user_name);
                weight.setText(user_weight);
                height.setText(user_height);

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return mview;
    }

}
```

**Edit**

**Change in the PeopleFragement.class**

```
import android.content.Context;


import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.kevin.sugar.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Kuro on 4/20/2016.
 */
public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    List mlist = new ArrayList();

    public ListDataAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Object object) {
        super.add(object);
        mlist.add(object);

    }

    static class LayoutHandler{
        TextView name, weight,height;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mlist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View mview = convertView;
        LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
        if(mview==null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mview = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.person_row,parent,false);
            layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
            layoutHandler.name = (TextView)mview.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
            layoutHandler.weight = (TextView)mview.findViewById(R.id.heatbeat);
            layoutHandler.height = (TextView)mview.findViewById(R.id.bpm_upper_lower);

            mview.setTag(layoutHandler);
        }else {
            layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) mview.getTag();
        }
        DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider)this.getItem(position);
        layoutHandler.name.setText(dataProvider.getName());
        layoutHandler.weight.setText(dataProvider.getWeight());
        layoutHandler.height.setText(dataProvider.getHeight());
        return mview;
    }
}
```

**ListDataAdapter.Class**

```
import android.content.Context;


import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.kevin.sugar.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Kuro on 4/20/2016.
 */
public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    List mlist = new ArrayList();

    public ListDataAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Object object) {
        super.add(object);
        mlist.add(object);

    }

    static class LayoutHandler{
        TextView name, weight,height;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mlist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View mview = convertView;
        LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
        if(mview==null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mview = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.person_row,parent,false);
            layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
            layoutHandler.name = (TextView)mview.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
            layoutHandler.weight = (TextView)mview.findViewById(R.id.heatbeat);
            layoutHandler.height = (TextView)mview.findViewById(R.id.bpm_upper_lower);

            mview.setTag(layoutHandler);
        }else {
            layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) mview.getTag();
        }
        DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider)this.getItem(position);
        layoutHandler.name.setText(dataProvider.getName());
        layoutHandler.weight.setText(dataProvider.getWeight());
        layoutHandler.height.setText(dataProvider.getHeight());
        return mview;
    }
}
```

**DataProvide.class**

```
public class DataProvider {

    private String name;
    private String weight;
    private String height;

    public DataProvider(String name,String weight,String height){
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(String weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(String height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

**Error Log**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.kevin.sugar, PID: 29352
                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.example.kevin.sugar.Fragments.PeopleFragment.onCreateView(PeopleFragment.java:40)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
                                                                                    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:610)
                                                                                    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:677)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2045)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1196)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1409)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1084)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5990)
                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: You are giveng your 3 TextViews all the values in the row. And the last one remains, since the loop ends. This is not how to work with a ListView: You must fill an Adapter and then pass the Adapter to the ListView. You should search for a tutorial on `custom rows in a ListView filled from a database in Android`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you explain the Adapter part? I didn't get it.

Comment: Create ArrayList with Adapter then work perfect.

Comment: Please have a look at `android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter`.  If you need some sample code, look at the samples in the SDK under `legacy\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\view\List7.java`

Comment: @BobMalooga I have taken you suggestion and created a Adapter. I have created this adapter from a video tutorial so I think I have made some error while making it for my app. While running my app crashes and prints the error log as mentioned in the question. I have added the all the code.

Comment: @krislarson Can you please into the code that I have posted. I have made changes after some help from Bob Malooga. I am new to android and I dont know if I can use SimpleCursorAdaptor. Is there any advantages to use this? Though I found some SimpleCursorAdaptor example but I dont know how to use it.

Comment: `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference` You are referencing a non instanced object, which - I suppose - is the ListView itself.

Comment: @BobMalooga Yes, I have been inflating the **fragment_people.xml** layout. Somehow the **fragment_people.xml** wasn't working. It was created while creating the PeopleFragment.class. I have created a custome **people_listview.xml** and it worked. The only problem now persist is the order of the content and auto update the list. To see the list update I need to close the app and restart it again.

Comment: Or **simply reload** the Activity or the Fragment which contains the ListView. Isn't it **easier**? By the way, in **none** of your shown java files a ListView widget is ever **imported, declared and instanced**.

Comment: Yes, when I try to do pull down and refresh, it doesn't update. Also, how can I change the order of the List to old --> new to new -->old. **New == Top**

Comment: ... use `... ODER BY YourField ASC|DESC` (ASC is optional, since it's the default).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the stack trace your listview is not found by JVM so it i throwing nullpointer exception. Here is the code snippet you have to use in order to display data in listview.

PeopleFragment.java

```
public class PeopleFragment extends Fragment {

private DateBaseHelper dateBaseHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
private List<DataProvider> mPersonList;
private ListDataAdapter mListDataAdapter;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View mview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_person, container, false);

    ListView listView = (ListView) mview.findViewById(R.id.lv_person);
    mPersonList = new ArrayList<>();
    dateBaseHelper = new DateBaseHelper(getContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = dateBaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = dateBaseHelper.getUserInformation();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            String user_name,user_weight,user_height;
            user_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Information.NAME));
            user_weight = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Information.WEIGHT));
            user_height = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Information.HEIGHT));
            DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(user_name,user_weight,user_height);
            mPersonList.add(dataProvider);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    mListDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.row_person,mPersonList);
    listView.setAdapter(mListDataAdapter);
    return mview;
  }
}
```

fragment_person.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_person"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

your DataProvider.java

```
public class DataProvider {

private String name;
private String weight;
private String height;

public DataProvider(String name,String weight,String height){
    this.name = name;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.height = height;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public void setWeight(String weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}

public String getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(String height) {
    this.height = height;
  }
}
```

ListDataAdapter.java

```
public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

List<DataProvider> mlist;

public ListDataAdapter(Context context, int resource,List<DataProvider> list )
{
    super(context, resource);
    mlist = list;
}

static class LayoutHandler{
    TextView name, weight,height;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mlist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mlist.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View mview = convertView;
    LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
    if(mview==null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mview = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_person,parent,false);
        layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
        layoutHandler.name = (TextView)mview.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        layoutHandler.weight = (TextView)mview.findViewById(R.id.tv_weight);
        layoutHandler.height = (TextView)mview.findViewById(R.id.tv_height);

        mview.setTag(layoutHandler);
    }else {
        layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) mview.getTag();
    }
    DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider)this.getItem(position);
    layoutHandler.name.setText(dataProvider.getName());
    layoutHandler.weight.setText(dataProvider.getWeight());
    layoutHandler.height.setText(dataProvider.getHeight());
    return mview;
   }
}
```

row_person.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_weight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_height"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

to update the data you don't need to reopen the application just need to notify your adapter with new set of data. Suppose your cursor data has got change and you are on the same page. so just need to clear old data from personList and add new data. Here is the code

```
public void updatePersonList(){
    mPersonList.clear();
    dateBaseHelper = new DateBaseHelper(getContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = dateBaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = dateBaseHelper.getUserInformation();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            String user_name,user_weight,user_height;
            user_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Information.NAME));
            user_weight = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Information.WEIGHT));
            user_height = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Information.HEIGHT));

          DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(user_name,user_weight,user_height);
          mPersonList.add(dataProvider);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
  mListDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Yes, yesterday I solved the problem. And I have replied to bob Malooga. Thanks for the reply :) anyway. I'll mark it as answred.

Comment: can you tell me where to call the **updatepersonList** method ?

Comment: Whenever your data gets changed and you are on the same page ie PersonFragment.java. Tak an example I have a dialog on the same fragment which add new Person detail in database. Now after adding the data in database we dismiss our dialog but added person will not reflect on list. So once we dismiss the dialog we call updatePersonList() methood and it will display the new person detail on the go. I hope I am being able to make you understand.

Comment: Got it. So I have been using a dialog box which appears after tapping on a icon in the Action bar [toolbar]. After doing the entry I click on the done button to add values into the database. I have code this part in the main activity. The fragment is called using this **viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new PeopleFragment(), "PEOPLE");** and the dialogbox is called using **onOptionsItemSelected()** method. I have added the updatePersonList in the PeopleFragment. Now, how to call this in Mainactivity under onOptionsItemSelected method?